# How to use Telerik RadScheduleView with custom appoinments?

Tags: wpf, xaml, telerik

I'm trying to create a schedule view to show custom appointments using [this tutorial](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/radscheduleview-features-appointments-custom-appointment.html) from Telerik. The problem is that I need to edit the style of the **EditAppointment** dialog, when I copy the default style using <kbd>Right Click</kbd> -> <kbd>Edit Template</kbd> -> <kbd>Edit a Copy</kbd> I get several compilation errors of type **Ambiguous Reference**. I read that those errors can be fixed using the fully qualified namespace (example `clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls`)  but I don't know which namespace use on each case, because there are at least two options for each error.

If anyone has faced this before it would be great to share a workaround for this task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik's support team suggested me to use this namespace:
`xmlns:telerikScheduleView="clr-namespace:Telerik.Windows.Controls;assembly=Telerik.Windows.Controls.ScheduleView"`

Full explanation can be found [here](https://www.google.com.cu/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.telerik.com%2Fforums%2Fambiguous-reference-error-when-editing-the-default-style-of-the-radscheduleview-control&ei=fOaQU_21DPHF8QHbsYGwDA&usg=AFQjCNE_8BdR6Lt0NjSpeqNzb_rMf31cMg&bvm=bv.68445247,d.b2U).